# How can I typeset this accented, dotless i?

Tags: accents

[image: Accent of the letter 'i']

See the rough sketch above. I am able to typeset the accented *i* shown in the middle (for which I used the `\v` macro) and, obviously, the plain and simple *i* shown on the left also. However, I can't figure out how to typeset the one shown on the right. How can I do that?

Comment: `\u{\i}` makes a rounded shape, `\v{\i}` an acute one.

Comment: @egreg, how to do this in math mode?

Comment: @Sigur `\text{\u{\i}}`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the breve accent in text mode use `\u{\i}`, for the *háček* use `\v{\i}`. In math mode, they are `\breve{\imath}` and `\check{\imath}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\verb|\u{\i}|: \u{\i}

\verb|\v{\i}|: \v{\i}

\verb|$\breve{\imath}\ne\check{\imath}$|: $\breve{\imath}\ne\check{\imath}$

\end{document}
```

[image]